# Making a graph from factory log data

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory, gephi

I want to summarize a graph that I created from factory log data.

In its raw form, the graph contains 234 nodes (the action a robot can perform) and around 4 million edges (the flow in the log data: robot 1 does action 1 at 23:45:32 --> robot 23 does action 334 at 23:45:33).

I have created the graph in Networkx as a Weighted DiGraph (the weight is the number of times a transition from, for example, action 1 --> action 334 happened) and visualized it in Gephi so you can see how it looks like (see image).

My first thought was analyzing this as a Directed Acyclic Graph since there are a few key events that seem to be happening most of the time (you can see that those events are in the middle and serve as the most important nodes where every process eventually ends).

I want to find the paths that lead to those nodes:

[image: bird-view of the graph]

However, when i check nx.is_tree(G), is_directed_acyclic_graph(G) or anything else, they all return false. My first question therefore is: What kind of graph am I looking at here? Is this some sort of special case graph? Because I cannot seem to find the right term for it.

My second question is, what are some strategies to automatically find the paths to those important nodes. For example, some of the end-nodes are errors. It would be great to know which chain/path/trace of nodes/edges lead to those errors most of the time.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: So the graph G = (V, E) embodies the actions of an agent (robot) -> V, and the sequence the robot did as edges? In your description however you mention multiple robots, how does that work? Is the graph ^ a depiction of superimposed graphs? It looks like a lot more nodes than 234... Edit: additionally is it possible for the robot to visit the same node twice in a sequence? In that case it is not a tree and not a DAG.

Comment: i think that for now, it is enough to focus on the transition of a action (334 to 222). And afterwards, i could add the attribute that it was the transition of robot1 who did 334 to robot34 who did 222). Or is this some information that should be incorporated immediately? If so, should i then make another graph of robots that serve as nodes and then merge them?....  Edit: i ran nx.info(g) and it says 234 nodes and 4402 edges. Also, it is possible to visit the same node twice as the same event in the log event can happen after each other hundreds of times.

Comment: `Also, it is possible to visit the same node twice as the same event in the log event can happen after each other hundreds of times`

Well there is your answer; it is not a DAG and not a tree due to the self edges/cycles

Comment: okay that is great to hear, i can exclude searching in that direction now! Do you also know a way to analyze this graph? One key thing that i want to do is filter paths or chains of events that happen very very frequenty, because those are just normal procedures in the factory. What would be the end goal is ending up with a graph of the unusual events, the chains that are not common...

Comment: There are many tools offered by network science (many of them implemented in networkx) that you can use to do this. One of the least computational expensive and most understable would (arguably) be centrality measures. Edit: spelling

Answer (score 0):

This is a directed graph.  As long as there is a path in your graph from one node back to itself, it has cycles.  So it is not acyclic.

In your case the same robot can do the same action more than once, so clearly there is a cycle.  Even if one robot did action 1 and then 2, another did action 2 and then 3, and yet another did action 3 and then 2, you'd still have a cycle.  Additionally, if there weren't a cycle, then eventually each robot would run out of possible tasks (because they can't repeat).  In fact, there would be certain actions in your graph such that once any robot does them, it never does anything again.

This graph you have is simply a weighted directed graph.

The simplest measure of the important nodes is their frequency.  In your case, this would be the sum of their weights in or the sum of their weights out (which should be equal, up to a correction for which nodes are the first/last actions performed by a robot in your dataset).

Other "centrality" measures exist.  You can find many of them at the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/centrality.html).  The fact that your graph is directed and weighted may affect whether the centrality measure has been implemented for the network (check the details of the documentation, and be aware that if you don't explicitly tell it to use the edge weights, it will treat the graph as unweighted).

Before blindly using one of these centrality measures, you should think about whether it makes sense for your context.